# Contains string in a list by sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I use mysql 5.1.72-community.

I have a table named team:

```
team_id          team_name
    1             US
    1             CH
    2             AD
    2             JP
    2             IT
    3             AU
    3             CL
    3             CU
```

and a table named person:

```
person_id        address
    10051        US. Idaho
    10152        US. Connecticut
    10053        CH. Aargau
    10054        CH. Bern
    10055        JP. Tokyo
    10056        JP. Ginza
    10057        Uneo of JP
```

Now I want create a view named person_view, like:

```
person_id     address        team_id
10051        US. Idaho          1
10152        US. Connecticut    1
10053        CH. Aargau         1
10054        CH. Bern           1
10055        JP. Tokyo          2
10056        JP. Ginza          2
10057        Uneo of JP         2
```

That means if person.address contains the team.team_name, then person_view.team_id = team.team_id.

How can I do this please?

Comment: Have a team_id column in your persons table.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you. that is an old project, have no person.team_id. I just want to do that by a view.

Comment: @xunitc Is the `team_name` in the `adress` column always on the left or right side? Or can it be anywhere in the `adress` column?

Comment: @ppijnenburg i didnt see 10057 at the time of posting thanks for pointing that out, i have deleted my answer

Comment: @ppijnenburg it can be anywhere in the address. Thank you, I see your first answer, it find some rows except 10057.

Comment: The answer from @Justinas Marozas should help you out then. Be aware though, using JOINS with LIKE can really hurt the performance. Since you want to create a view, this query keeps getting executed everytime you request data from the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the `team_id` column in `persons` table if you can and join on it. If you can't - you can try doing this:

```
CREATE VIEW person_view
AS
SELECT p.person_id,
    t.address,  
    t.team_id
FROM person p 
-- if team name can be anywhere in the address:
JOIN team t ON p.address LIKE CONCAT('%', t.team_name, '%');
-- -- if team name will always be in front of address:
-- JOIN team t ON p.address LIKE CONCAT(t.team_name, '%');
```

Comment: Thank you. I try it in mysql 5.1.72-community, but it can not run. I just copy it and run. what is my wrong please?

Comment: @xunitc , my bad. I've updated code to use `CONCAT` instead of `+` now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (sorry I can't test it):

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.address, t.team_id
FROM team t, person p
WHERE t.team_name like p.address
```

Comment: Thank you, but it can not work for me, maybe I have some mistakes.

Comment: check column names, table names spells

Comment: Thank you, and that need  p.address like t.team_name, and % needed too.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW person_view
AS
SELECT p.person_id,
    t.address,  
    t.team_id
FROM person p ,
team t where p.address LIKE '%' || t.team_name || '%';
```

Try this

Comment: Thank you, but the view is too large by this sql. maybe Cartesian product.

Comment: Is it containing duplicates?

Comment: Yes. it will put 10053,"CH. Aargau" to team_id 1,2,3, and term_id 1 twice and so on.